# Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1 / The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to start the webdriver manager from command line, after having installed latest versions node, protractor and java. 
The whole log after trying webdriver-manager start command:

> [16:28:54] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\F&J\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.43.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\F&J\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.23.0.exe -jar C:\Users\F&J\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -port 4444
>   [16:28:54] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 13024
>   Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)
>      or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)
>   where options include:
>   -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
>   -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
>       -server       to select the "server" VM
>                     The default VM is server.
>
> -cp 
>   -classpath 
>                 A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>                 and ZIP archives to search for class files.
>   -D=
>                 set a system property
>   -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
>                 enable verbose output
>   -version      print product version and exit
>   -version:
>                 Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>                 in a future release.
>                 require the specified version to run
>   -showversion  print product version and continue
>   -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
>                 Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>                 in a future release.
>                 include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
>   -? -help      print this help message
>   -X            print help on non-standard options
>   -ea[:...|:]
>   -enableassertions[:...|:]
>                 enable assertions with specified granularity
>   -da[:...|:]
>   -disableassertions[:...|:]
>                 disable assertions with specified granularity
>   -esa | -enablesystemassertions
>                 enable system assertions
>   -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
>                 disable system assertions
>   -agentlib:[=]
>                 load native agent library , e.g. -agentlib:hprof
>                 see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
>   -agentpath:[=]
>                 load native agent library by full pathname
>   -javaagent:[=]
>                 load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
>   -splash:
>                 show splash screen with specified image
>
> See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   [16:28:54] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1

Comment: Tried reinstalling Java JRE and SDK, doing the webdriver-manager clean, turning off firewall, switching users(to something that doesn't have special symbols), installing an older version of the webdriver, but so far nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that special characters in the folder names are not handled very well.

The command would run as far as " I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\F&", which was not a valid path.